# Git submodule .gitignore still tracks file

Tags: php, git, github, gitignore

My problem is very simple.

I have project, this project includes as a submodule another project.
This submodule has a .gitignore as follows:

```
*~
~*
.DS_Store
nbproject
core.ini.php
```

Yet, every time I create a new core.ini.php file (for local specification purposes), the file gets included in the watched file list, committing it into the repository.
So despite the .gitignore of both the project AS WELL as the submodule specifying to ignore that file, it still gets added.

Here is just a screenshot to show that it is indeed added:

[image: .gitignore addition]

I would appreciate any advise or help. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried removing it from the `.gitignore`, deleting it, committing the delete, then reinstating the line in in `.gitignore`?

Comment: @DanielMay +1 Worked like a charm! Thank you very much!

Comment: @DanielMay do you mind posting that as an answer so that I can mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment on the OP, it looks like you probably added that file to the index at some point prior to adding it to the `.gitignore` file.

It's fairly easy to get yourself into this tight spot where git won't track the delete of the file (because it's already in the `.gitignore`!) - so the easiest way to achieve what you need is to:

1. Remove the specific file from the `.gitignore` file
2. Delete the file
3. Commit this deletion action
4. Add the line back into the `.gitignore`
5. Re-add your ignored file.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `git rm  --cached  filename` (in this case, `git rm --cached core.ini.php`) and commit the change using `git commit -m "msg"` and you will be done.

Comment: +1 Great solution, I wasn't aware you could do this.